# Fedora 17 : hotkey for terminal

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

Each time, if I want to use the terminal, I press the super key, type "terminal" in the search box, and enter to select the terminal icon.

How can I have a hotkey to open the terminal. (I do not say hotkey: control + alt + Fn because it will open a full-console, not what I want). I just want a terminal window.

I have searched all keyboard shortcuts but I don't see any option to select a hotkey for this purpose. I just see only one option: "Hotkey to enter the command". When using this hotkey, it will appear a small popup, but I don't know what command exists. (and it doesn't look like terminal)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Open System Settings

- select Keyboard,
- select Shortcuts Tab,
- the last item is 'Custom Shortcuts'
- press [+]
- enter Name: Terminal
- into  Command: enter 'gnome-terminal' (without quotes)
- press Apply
- click in the newly created line on 'Disabled'
- press key combination which you want to use for terminal (e.g. Alt-Home).

You're set.

Comment: Thanks :) I don't know this console can call by 'gnome-terminal'. But other question, why all hotkey is allow, but when I define : super + R. It won't work. do you know why ?

Comment: There are many other terminals available for linux, so it does not have to be gnome-terminal, but it can be xterm,aterm etc. Not sure why Super-R does not work, but I can confirm it does not work for me neither.

Comment: Crash, @hqt what desktop you are using? I succeeded to assign and use super+R with XFCE

Comment: For Fedora 20, it's also necessary to mention that you have to click the "Disabled" word to allow it to let you specify a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: To specify the size, you can use [this advice](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9623/terminal-key-shortcut/): gnome-terminal --profile=Default --geometry=95x35+250+60

Comment: On Fedora 25 you need to click on area marked with a "+" at the bottom of the list to add a custom shortcut.